# Taglib inside Maven dependency jar. How do I configure this taglib inside the web.xml?

Tags: java, jsp, maven, web.xml, taglib

So I used to configure my taglib like that:

```
<jsp-config> 
   <taglib> 
      <taglib-uri>myTags</taglib-uri> 
      <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/lib/mylib-2.0.1.jar</taglib-location> 
   </taglib> 
</jsp-config>
```

But now mylib-2.0.1.jar is a maven dependency, so of course it is NOT on /WEB-INF/lib.

How do I do to configure my taglib so I can do that in my JSPs:

```
<%@ taglib uri="myTags" prefix="mt" %>
```

**EDIT1:** To clafiry, the taglib.tld is inside the META-INF inside the jar so you can access the tld by referencing the jar itself. That's a convenient way to distribute your taglib along with the web application framework jar.

**EDIT2:** When we deploy the webapp, the jar will be in the WEB/INF/lib. But during development, inside eclipse, using m2eclipse, the jar will NOT. So eclipse complains it cannot find the taglib no where, because the jar is not there and I cannot reference my jar in the web.xml.

Comment: Why is mylib-2.0.1.jar `not` on /WEB-INF/lib?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to configure anything in `web.xml`, if the taglib is in `\META-INF\taglib.tld` inside your jar, it is automatic, Tomcat already recognizes.

You can use the jsp :

```
<% @ Taglib prefix = "my" uri = "http://www.mytags.com/"%>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you add in your POM the taglig dependency, it will be added in the WEB-INF/lib directory of your webapp.

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>yourTageLib</groupId>
     <artifactId>mylib</artifactId>
     <version>2.0.1</version>
     <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: Can you add a taglib to Maven? The taglib comes inside my jar, in the META-INF directory.

Comment: In our case, the tag lib is not in scope compile, but in scope provided. It is part of the server libraries.