# Adding Spring Security JspTagLib to a Freemarker template - issues with controller unit tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jsp-tags, freemarker

I have added Springs jsp security taglib to a freemarker template because I'm using freemarker for the view of my web app rather than jsps.  For anyone searching for how to set this up, I found [Adding spring library for usage of JSP Taglibs for security in Freemarker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069602/adding-spring-library-for-usage-of-jsp-taglibs-for-security-in-freemarker) to be a very helpful question.  In summary, add the following to the *.ftl file you wish to use the tags in:

```
<#assign security=JspTaglibs["http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"] />
```

Then assuming you're using maven add the following to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Once I set this up I ran my spring controller unit tests and they all failed.  The problem was they needed el-api.jar and jsp-api.jar to resolve how to render the Jsp tags.  These are included as part of the container in which the web app runs (tomcat), hence they weren't needed for normal running of the application.  So I added these as maven dependencies within test scope.

```
<!-- Required for spring controller junit tests, due to use of jspTagLib for security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

<!-- Required for spring controller junit tests, due to use of jspTagLib for security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

With this fixed my tests also threw an error that they couldn't find the mapping for the .tld file even though it is included when you add the spring-security-taglibs maven dependency.

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is freemarker.template.TemplateModelException: No mapping defined for http://www.springframework.org/security/tags
The failing instruction (print stack trace for 2 more):
==> #assign security = JspTaglibs["http:/...  [in template "global/menu.ftl" at line 1, column 1]
```

In order to fix this I also had to add security.tld to WEB-INF/lib/.  Everything works now but it's not good that I need to have the tag library security.tld in two places (spring-security-taglibs-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar under META-INF and WEB-INF/lib).

My question is does anyone know how I can avoid this duplication of having security.tld in two places just to be able to run unit tests, I would rather just have it included in the jar file and not add it to WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: Can you put the TLD in a path where it is available during the unit tests, but does not clutter up your release?

Comment: I'm putting it in WEB-INF/lib at the moment which is ok, it's just that this is a second copy of the file.  I'm thinking the problem is something to do with how maven handles jar file dependencies for running junit tests.  I have tried adding all tomcat jar files to the classpath for junit tests, in case one of these jars was directing the app where to look for the .tld, but I still get the same issue.

Comment: Does it work if you put your TLD under `.../test/resources` or `.../test/resources/WEB-INF/lib`?  Both maven and FTL JSP taglib support are things I'm not really expert on, but no one else seems to be stepping up to help. :-)

Comment: A good idea but I just tried it and it gives me the same error.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Taglib inside Maven dependency jar. How do I configure this taglib inside the web.xml?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7682680/taglib-inside-maven-dependency-jar-how-do-i-configure-this-taglib-inside-the-we)