# Intellij: Integration test with Spring and Freemarker

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, spring-security, freemarker, spring-test

I am trying to run Integration Tests in Intellij, using freemarker.

I had a problem with the JspTaglibs that I work around thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20100276/adding-spring-security-jsptaglib-to-a-freemarker-template-issues-with-controll), and I did add to the pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

and added to /WEB-INF/lib [security.tld](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spring-projects/spring-security/4.1.x/taglibs/src/main/resources/META-INF/security.tld)

- If I run all the tests with Maven, it works
- If I run the tests individually with Intellij, it works.
- If I run **all the tests** with Intellij, some tests fails:

  Caused by: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: No visible WebSecurityExpressionHandler instance could be found in the application context. There must be at least one in order to support expressions in JSP 'authorize' tags.

How can I fix this problem ?

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>yyy</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>xxx</name>

    <properties>
    <spring.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <postgresql.version>9.4-1201-jdbc41</postgresql.version>
    </properties>
    <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>

    <!--spring boot-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <!--custom-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-hamcrest</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version> <!-- makesure correct version here -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.imgscalr</groupId>
        <artifactId>imgscalr-lib</artifactId>
        <version>4.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--test-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
    <finalName>xxx</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**EDIT**

I think I found something important. In this application I am logging the user after he register in the website, using this line:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

If you comment this line out, running all tests works fine from Intellij. If you leave this line on, tests fails randomly once a test executes this line. It starts to feel like a Intellij bug.

Comment: Wait.  If the tests *reliably* pass after omission of that line, but *sporadically* fail due to inclusion of that line, how is that IntelliJ's fault?

Comment: @Makoto it works with maven. Is it good enough ?

Comment: Are you running the tests through Maven in IntelliJ?

Comment: @Makoto 1 - `mvn test` from the terminal works. Always. 2 - Running all tests from Intellij creates this weird problem. 3 - There is empirical relationship in Intellij: tests works if you comment the line out; tests fails if you leave the line. I am currently using the default settings of Intellij to run the tests. Any directions to check if using maven or more details about how to set it up ?

Comment: Let me rephrase - are you running the tests in IntelliJ through the Maven plugin sidebar, or through some other way?

Comment: @Makoto I understand you now :). Maven plugin sidebar works. It fails when using /src/test/java, right button "Run All Test" (shortcut CTRL + Shift + F10)